# Modify all integers in 2d list and make them even

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this through the visualizer it only modifies the first element in the 2d list. How do I make it so that the it runs throught the entire list.

```
     def make_even(xss):
        for i in range(len(xss)):
        for j in range(len(xss)):
            if xss[i][j] % 2!= 0:
                xss[i][j] += 3
            return xss

    xss = [[1,2,3],[],[4,5]]
    make_even(xss)
    print(xss)
```

Comment: I think you have to correct your indentation as python detects so the nesting of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

So first off you need to correct your indentation in your code:

```
def make_even(xss):
    for i in range(len(xss)):
        for j in range(len(xss)):
            if xss[i][j] % 2!= 0:
                xss[i][j] += 3
    return xss
```

However, because both your loops use `len(xss)`, they expect an array of 3 lists each with 3 elements. If you'd want each list to have variable numbers of elements you should do this instead:

```
def make_even(xss):
    for i in range(len(xss)):
        for j in range(len(xss[i])):
            if xss[i][j] % 2!= 0:
                xss[i][j] += 3
    return xss
```

Which returns: `[[4, 2, 6], [], [4, 8]]`

However, there are two obvious changes I would make:

1. Your if statement should be `if xss[i][j] % 2 == 1`, since it's more readable.
2. You can make a number even by adding 1. (If 3 is required for your specs that's fine).

Also, this is totally doable in a single line (any line would work):

```
# List comprehensions only
xss = [[(x + 3 if x % 2 == 1 else x) for x in row] for row in xss]
# map and lamdbas (returns lists)
xss = list(map(lambda row: list(map((lambda x: x + 3 if x % 2 == 1 else x),row)), xss))
# map and lamdbas (returns iterables)
xss = map(lambda row: map((lambda x: x + 3 if x % 2 == 1 else x),row), xss)
```

Although personally, I think the list comprehensions is the easiest to read.